# Find $e^{At}$ of the matrix given below.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

> Find $e^{At}$ of the matrix given below.
> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 1 & -2 \\
> -1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & -1
> \end{pmatrix}$$

---

If this was a diagonal matrix I could take $e$ power of every quantity. Or, else, since $e^{At}$ is the fundamental matrix such that when $t=0$ gives the identity, Is it enough to find the fundamental matrix considering this as a ODE system.

Comment: What if you diagonalized it?

Comment: A hint: $A^4=I$.

Comment: If this is not a diagonal matrix try to write it as $A=CDC^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal. Then notice that $A^n = CD^nC^{-1}$ so $e^{At} = Ce^{Dt}C^{-1}$

Comment: If A weren't diagonalisible, The best way would to use Jordan Decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2,3} = -i,i, 1$, so this matrix is diagonalizable.

The corresponding eigenvectors are

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-i\\1\end{pmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\i\\1\end{pmatrix}, v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

$P$ is formed using the eigenvector columns and we can write the exponential as

$$e^{At} = P e^{Dt}P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&-1\\ -i & i & 1 \\ 1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-it}& 0 & 0\\ 0 &e^{it}&0 \\ 0&0&e^t\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{i}{2} & \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \\
 -\frac{i}{2} & -\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

From Euler's Formula, we know $e^{i a t} = \cos at + i \sin at$.

This reduces our result to

$$e^{At} = \begin{pmatrix}
 e^t+\sin (t) & \sin (t) & -e^t-\sin (t)+\cos (t) \\
 \cos (t)-e^t & \cos (t) & e^t-\sin (t)-\cos (t) \\
 \sin (t) & \sin (t) & \cos (t)-\sin (t) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just plug in:

$$e^{A t} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(A t)^k}{k!}$$

$$ = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sin (t)+e^t & \sin (t) & \cos (t)-e^t-\sin (t) \\
 \cos (t)-e^t & \cos (t) & -\cos (t)+e^t-\sin (t) \\
 \sin (t) & \sin (t) & \cos (t)-\sin (t) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: How did you find the infinite sum?